# How to change SMS sender number in GAMMU?

Tags: sms, gammu

i would like to ask. I need to change SMS sender number in Gammu

http://wammu.eu/gammu/

Is it possible? And if Yes, how?

Thanks for any advice.

Im sending via wavecom fastrack GSM modem.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, "it's filled in by SMSC" http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.gammu/3617